# Setting RGB Colors with XSSFColor

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to set an RGB Color Value using [XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/extensions/XSSFCellFill.html#setFillForegroundColor(int)) `setFillForeground()` method below

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook();
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
Style.cloneStyleFrom(headerStyle);
Style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(215,228,188)); //accepts a short value
style.setFillForegroundColor(color .getIndexed());

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

I'm passing the short value however my foreground is getting set to black no matter what the RGB value. I haven't yet discovered why this is - any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`getIndexed()` method in `XSSFColor`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#getIndexed()) has Javadocs that state that it's for backwards compatibility.  Basically, XSSF has no pallette, so it's useless to set an index of color in a `CellStyle`.

However, XSSF has its own method of setting the foreground color in a style -- using the colors directly.  Use the [overload of `setFillBackgroundColor` that directly takes a `XSSFColor`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor)).  It only exists in `XSSFCellStyle`, not the interface `CellStyle`, so cast it as a `XSSFCellStyle` first.

```
((XSSFCellStyle) style).setFillForegroundColor(color);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a ton, and for the explanation

Comment: The ONLY solution that works in NPOI...thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

You can check the example provided by the [Apache Colors and Fills](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills)

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell( 0);
cell.setCellValue("custom XSSF colors");
XSSFCellStyle style1 = wb.createCellStyle();
style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
style1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```